# Send head before the controller completes rendering

Tags: html, optimization, zend-framework, httpresponse

How can one send `<head>` contents before the controller finishes? The idea is to start loading CSS as soon as possible (don't wait for controller action).

Sample scenario:

```
// in the controller
sleep(5);
```

This gives:

blank page for 5 seconds -> display the `head` -> start loading CSS -> `body`

The flow I want to get is:

Send `head` -> start loading CSS -> wait for the controller -> send rest of the page (body)

The `<head>` is now in `layout.phtml`, which later includes the index controller script (`index.phtml`).

Maybe I could have `<head>` as a partial and send it somehow before the whole layout?

Comment: You won't be able to directly handle this that way, for 1 request you get 1 response. A solution would be to make a call to your controller wich renders nothing but the layout and then add a javascript async call which would fetch the remaining of the html (without the layout).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create an abstract controller that all controllers extend, and in the `onDispatch` function render the head template and flush:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {
  $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
  $content = new ViewModel();
  $content->setTemplate('path/to/head.phtml');
  $content = $renderer->render($content);
  echo $content;
  flush();
  parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

Drawbacks to this approach:

- You have no access to the `headTitle`, `headMeta`, `headLink`, `headScript` and other view helpers elsewhere in your application (it is possible in a controller or viewscript to add a style sheet and js plugin for just that page).
- You will be unable to perform redirects as a response has already been sent
- You can't gzip the content as well as flushing it
- > [Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those browsers to display the page.](http://php.net/flush)

In theory, you could use this approach to load all static content in the layout before `echo`ing `$this->content` - such as logo, navigation, search bar, etc etc.

As I've stated, this breaks redirects meaning helpers and plugins such a [`PostRedirectGet`](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-post-redirect-get-plugin) will not work.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Op asks for deferred rendering via php which's not possible. You answer will send head.phtml's content will close connection as expected.

Comment: It is not possible to do a partial rendering (render top part of `layout.phtml` then, some time later, the rest of `layout.phtml`). What the OP has to do is move the head content into a new view script (`path/to/head.phtml`) which will be rendered before `layout.phtml`. I have tested the above code in a local project (and adding `sleep(15)` to the `indexAction`) and it worked as intended.

Comment: read again. he's trying to do;

send head tag, wait 5 secs for load css, then send rest of the page which's not possible via solid php. if you put "sleep(5)" anywhere, page will wait as blank for 5 secs.

Comment: OP does not want to load the css then send the rest of the page, OP wants to reduce download time by sending the `head` to the browser immediately (on my local project this takes 500ms) so the browser can request and load the css while the server / controller finishes doing its thing (e.g. `sleep(15)`) before the server sends the rest of the layout / view. As the browser has already requested and loaded the css, it can render the page immediately. Otherwise browser is waiting 15 seconds for full page before it can start requesting the css files, wait for the requests to return the [cont]

Comment: stylesheets and THEN render the page.

Comment: The exact wording of the question is `How can one send <head> contents before the controller finishes?` and this answer fulfils the question.